# Dark Ring I - Prepare to Combo Edition™

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, pattern, story

My friend showed me a game recently, it's a little indie game called Dark Ring I, it's honestly pretty good and... I should get to the matter at hand. I'm reaching the final boss, and I tried looking into my trusty game manual to see what combo I needed to input to defeat him, but, somehow the page got torn off at that exact spot! I wanted to try and brute-force it, but even with only three different actions (blocking, rolling and attacking), the sequence could be very long, and it would take me years, maybe centuries!
So please, help me find that combo, I've written down some of the combos to kill other bosses, maybe it can help you...

| Enemy | Combo |
| --- | --- |
| Wolf | **⟳⟳⛨⟳⟳⛨⛨⛨** (ARARABRRBBAB) |
| Neeto, The Dead | **⛨⟳⟳⛨⟳⛨⛨⟳⛨⟳⟳** (BRRBRABBRBRR) |
| Lead Golem | **⛨⟳⟳⛨⟳⟳⛨⛨⟳⟳⟳⟳** (BARRABRRBBRARRR) |
| Great Dog Cif | **⛨⟳⛨⟳⛨⛨⛨⛨** (BRBRBBBAB) |
| Handus, Father of the Void | **⟳⟳⟳⛨⟳⛨⛨⛨⟳⟳** (ARRRABRBBBRR) |
| Gwin | **???** |

(A is Attack, B is Block, R is Roll)

Comment: Most games have random moves and a random amount of moves for each boss. Do you have a specific reason you put this question?

Comment: @VarunW. Puzzle has the "story" tag, I just gave it a bit of backstory, I don't *actually* need help beating a boss

Comment: Oh my bad I did not see it.

Comment: Also I think one of the characters don't show up. I see the sword and the roll but not the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combo you should use for Gwin is:

> ⛨⟳⟳⟳⛨⛨⟳⟳

Because:

> Each combo can be split into blocks of three actions.
>  Taking  = 2, ⟳ = 1 and ⛨ = 0, each block of three can we read as a ternary number between 0 and 26, which encodes a letter of the boss' name.
>  E.g. For Wolf:
>  ⟳ = $212_3 = 23 = W$
>  ⟳⛨ = $120_3 = 15 = O$
>  ⟳⟳⛨ = $110_3 = 12 = L$
>  ⛨⛨ = $020_3 = 6 = F$
>
>   So for Gwin we have:
>  $G = 7 = 021_3$ = ⛨⟳
>  $W = 23 = 212_3$ = ⟳
>  $I = 9 = 100_3$ = ⟳⛨⛨
>  $N = 14 = 112_3$ = ⟳⟳

Answer (score 2):

The combo is

> ⛨⟳⟳⟳⛨⛨⟳⟳

Because

> Each letter is represented by 3 symbols, the digits of a base 3 number. Block for 0, Roll for 1, Attack for 2. The number in base 10 is corresponds to the letter in the English alphabet. 021 212 100 112 for GWIN.

⟳⟳⛨⟳⟳⛨⛨⛨

> WOLF

⛨⟳⟳⛨⟳⛨⛨⟳⛨⟳⟳

> DEAD

⛨⟳⟳⛨⟳⟳⛨⛨⟳⟳⟳⟳

> GOLEM

⟳⟳⟳⛨⟳⛨⛨⛨⟳⟳

> VOID

Comment: fljx was faster, the reasoning is correct, there's just a small typo for the last symbol in the sequence. Please accept that one as the correct one.

Comment: A mix of both your answers would be ideal, but I respect your choice. I'll accept it as soon, as the answer gets fixed.

Comment: Pesky unicode characters. I've fixed it now.