# Dark Ring II - Scholar of the First Combo™

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, pattern, story

I need your help again people! After finishing [Dark Ring I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115218/dark-ring-i-prepare-to-combo-edition), thanks to you all, I went and bought the second game in the series. It's a lot more complicated, but I also learned a lot more from the combo system!
Before using a combo, I decide to look at it and check for certain things from left to right:

- Attacking twice is way too risky, I prefer changing  (AA) with **⟳** (AR).
- Blocking and then attacking can be replaced with a Parry and Riposte **⚔** (P), which also removes the need for the last two inputs from the sequence, at most up to and excluding the swapped in Parry. It even stacks, so the more Parries, the smaller the combo!
- Double rolling isn't all that useful, I prefer replacing the second roll with a Heal ✚ (H).
- Some combos are incomplete, if after all the rules, the combo doesn't end with an attack (or a parry), I need to add one!
- I analyze the combo as much as I need to, sometimes taking more than one read of it to properly "fix" all of it.

Thanks to this, I've manage to reduce some combos to nearly nothing, look:

| Enemy | Combo | Enhanced Combo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Final Giant | **⛨⛨⛨⛨⟳** (ABABABBAR) | **⚔⚔** (APP) |
| Forlord | **⛨⛨** (BAB) | **⚔** (P) |

But here I am, nearing the end again, and I've noticed my copy of the manual is missing a boss combo, AGAIN! (That'll teach me to buy a used copy of the game) So please, I beg you all, help me find that combo and finish my journey.
Like last time, I've also written down some of the combos for prior bosses.

| Enemy | Enhanced Combo |
| --- | --- |
| The Final Giant | **⚔⚔** (APP) |
| Royal Rat Rumble | **⛨⚔⛨⚔** (ABPBP) |
| Flexing Sentinel | **⚔⚔** (PP) |
| Arcsinh, The Awakened Dragon | **⛨⛨⟳⚔⛨⛨⟳⚔** (BBRAPBBRP) |
| Diamond King And His Frog Knights | **⛨⟳✚⟳⚔⛨⛨⟳⚔⟳⚔** (BRHRPBBRPRP) |
| Natashandra | **⟳✚** (RHA) |
| King Von Brick | **???** |

Comment: Are the rules complete? Maybe I'm reading something wrong, I don't see how replacing Block followed by Attack (BA) with Parry (P) reduces the overall length by 2. For Forlord I'm getting BAB -> PB -> PBA -> PP, which doesn't quite match the enhanced combo. I might be misunderstanding the "can't erase past itself" part, are we supposed to remove extra actions as part of the BA -> P replacement?

Comment: @Moghwyn If the combo is BABARR you'll end up with PP, when a BA is changed into a Parry, it *also* removes the last two characters from the sequence

Comment: In other words, "Blocking and then attacking can be replaced with a Parry, which also removes the last two characters from the sequence, at most up to and excluding the swapped in Parry"?

Comment: @Moghwyn Precisely, may I use your definition ?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: I'm getting BRHRPBBRPRP for Diamond King And His Frog Knight. Rolling as second last character originates from replacing AA with AR as first modification step. Typo or some rule I didn't apply correctly?

Comment: @Moghwyn A typo on my part, I write those puzzles on paper first, and that line in particular was written over several times, my bad, editing now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combo is

> RPRHRP

This is done by

> Taking the first character of each word, taking the index of this character in the English alphabet (A = 1, Z = 26), writing the index as base 3 number (1 = 001, 26 = 222), replacing 0 with B, 1 with R, 2 with A, applying the transformation rules.

The Final Giant

> TFG -> 202 020 021 -> ABABABBAR -> APBABB-> APP

Forlord

> F -> 020 -> BAB -> P

Royal Rat Rumble

> RRR -> 200 200 200 -> ABBABBABB -> ABPBBA -> ABPBP

Flexing Sentinel

> FS -> 020 201 -> BABABR -> PBA -> PP

Arcsinh, The Awakened Dragon

> ATAD -> 001 202 001 011 -> BBRABABBRBRR -> BBRAPBBRB -> BBRAPBBRBA -> BBRAPBBRP

Diamond King And His Frog Knights

> DKAHFK -> 011 102 001 022 020 102 -> BRRRBABBRBAABABRBA -> BRRRBABBRBARBABRBA -> BRRRPBBRBARBABR -> BRRRPBBRPRBA -> BRRRPBBRPRP -> BRHRPBBRPRP

Natashandra

> N -> 112 -> RRA -> RHA

King Von Brick

> KVB -> 102 211 002 -> RBAARRBBA -> RBARRRBBA -> RPRRRB -> RPRHRB -> RPRHRBA -> RPRHRP

Comment: Congrats! Sorry again for the small typos and mistakes, hope you enjoyed! Stay tuned for the next game!