# Dark Ring III - The Combo City™

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, pattern, story

So uhm, it's a bit embarrassing, but I've spilled some coffee on my brand new Dark Ring III combo manual (Thank you all lots for the [previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115218/dark-ring-i-prepare-to-combo-edition) [games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115229/dark-ring-ii-scholar-of-the-first-combo)!). I've been loving the game, I even bought it brand new this time! But it seems fate had other plans for me and decided to, once again, ruin the last combo in the game for me.
So I come to you once again, hoping you can help me with my endeavor so I finally finish this great series once and for all! This time, I decided to play a lighter build, so no more blocking; I also change a few other things in this order:

- No more blocking! All **⛨** (B) are replaced by **⟳** (R)
- Attacking and rolling afterwards is way too risky in this game, I prefer changing **⟳** (AR) into Magic **❈** (M)
- Every 4th **❈** (M) I won't use Magic but Heal instead **✚** (H)
- Every 5th **⟳** (R) I won't Roll and Heal instead **✚** (H)
- If the combo has two Heals next to each other **✚✚** (HH) I prefer going for a Crit instead of heal a second time **✚⭗** (HC)
- Remove the last three inputs in the sequence per Crit **⭗** (C)
- If, after all these steps, the combo doesn't end with any kind of attack , **❈** or **⭗** (A, M or C), add an Attack  (A)

As always, here are some samples of my modified combo manual:

| **Enemy** | Remixed Combo |
| --- | --- |
| Bacon of the Deep | **⟳⟳❈⟳⟳✚⟳❈❈✚❈❈⟳⟳⟳❈** (RRMRRHRMMHMAMRRRM) |
| Vozh of the Boring Valley | **❈⟳❈❈✚❈❈❈⟳✚⟳⟳✚❈❈❈⟳⟳⟳⟳✚⟳⟳** (MRAAMAMHMMAMRAHRRHMMMRRRRHRRA) |
| The Abyss Catchers | **❈❈❈⟳✚⟳❈⟳⟳✚⟳❈❈⟳⟳⟳✚⭗** (MMAMRAHRMRRHRMMRRRAAHC) |
| Devourer of Mods | **⟳⟳⟳❈⟳❈✚❈⟳⟳✚⟳⟳✚⟳⟳⟳❈⟳** (RRRMRMHMRRHRRHRRRMRA) |
| Father Noel and Sister Frost | **⟳❈❈❈✚⟳⟳⟳❈✚⟳⟳⟳❈⟳✚❈⟳✚⟳❈❈⟳⟳❈✚⭗❈⟳** (RMMMAAHRRRMHRRRMRHMRHRMAMRRMHCMRA) |
| Brave Knight Gavin | **⟳⟳❈⟳❈⟳✚⟳❈⟳✚❈⟳❈❈✚❈⟳✚⟳** (RRAMRMRHRMRHMRAAMMHMRHRA) |
| Son of Wonder | **???** |

Hint (or "Guys guys, I found something that might help!"):

> If the combo doesn't contain a Crit, then checking the length might help!

Hint 2

> It functions the same way as the other two games, but what does it use this time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final remixed combo for Son of Wonder is

> ❈⟳⟳⟳❈❈✚❈⟳❈✚⟳❈⟳ (MRRRMMHMRMHRMRA)

As with the previous Dark Ring games,

> The letters are converted to numbers (A = 1, Z = 26), and then written in base 3 (1 = 001, 26 = 222). In the original combos B=0, R=1, and A=2.

For this installment

> The combos for the boss fights are coded as the consonants of the full name (Bacon of the Deep=BCNFTHDP, Son of Wonder=SNFWNDR)

With the letters to be converted to the original combo, it is time to translate to the remixed combo using the rules provided.

> SNFWNDR => 201 112 020 212 112 011 200 => ABR RRA BAB ARA RRA BRR ABB => Replace all B's with Rs => ARR RRA RAR ARA RRA RRR ARR => Replace AR with M's => MRRRMMMMRMRRMR => Sub in H's for every 4th M and every 5th R => MRRRMMHMRMHRMR => Since it does not end in an attack action, add on an A => MRRRMMHMRMHRMRA

---

**Example:**

Bacon of the Deep ⟳⟳❈⟳⟳✚⟳❈❈✚❈❈⟳⟳⟳❈

> RRMRRHRMMHMAMRRRM => RRMRRRRMMMMAMRRRM => RRA_RRR_RRA_RAR_ARA_RAA_RRR_RAR => BCNFTHDP => 002 010 112 020 202 022 011 121 => BBA_BRB_RRA_BAB_ABA_BAA_BRR_RAR

Comment: If additional translations need to be written out let me know and I can add them too

Comment: Congrats! I planned on calling the boss "Soq of Wonder", but it just doesn't sound (nor look) as good as Son, it would have made use of every rule though!